How to Update Acumatica Default 20.200.001 to 22.200.001 Service Reference in Visual Studio
I am trying to update my references from Acumatica endpoint version 20.200.001 to 22.200.001 because only the later version contains mappings for Invoice line detail field Tax Category.
Current Reference
But when I update these references to Acumatica.Default_22.200.001 (updated all versions to latest version 5.3) I get this error for the namespace using Acumatica.Auth.Api; which worked perfectly fine before.
Reference Error
Error   CS0234  The type or namespace name 'Auth' does not exist in the namespace 'Acumatica' (are you missing an assembly reference?)  SkillInvestAPIIntegration   C:\PROJECTS\MYOB\SkillInvest\CODE NOT MODIFIED\SkillInvestAPIIntegration\SkillInvestAPIIntegration\SkillInvestAPIIntegration\Rep\MYOBFunctions.cs   1   Active

Could I please get some assistance on this, thank you!

I was able to load the new API reference using the below method.
using Acumatica.Default_22_200_001.Model;
using Acumatica.RESTClient.Client;

using static Acumatica.RESTClient.AuthApi.AuthApiExtensions;
using static Acumatica.RESTClient.ContractBasedApi.ApiClientExtensions;  

var client = new ApiClient(siteURL);
client.Login(username, password, tenant, branch, locale);

